# Tensorflow neural network - combined sigmoid prediction probabilities consistently exceed 100%

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy, softmax, sigmoid-curve

I have a very basic Tensorflow model:

```
self.model = models.Sequential()
self.model.add(layers.Dense(32, input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
self.model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation="relu"))
self.model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation="sigmoid"))
self.model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss= "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
self.model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

Where `y_train` contains classes numbered 0, 1, or 2 based on whether certain values exceed a value to the positive or negative side (i.e., 2 > `value`, 0 < `-value`, and 1 is in between `-value` and `-value`).

However, whenever I run this, it consistently predicts values that, in combination, sum to greater than 100%.  Here's an example of the output of predictions made by this model.

```
[[0.6157769  0.6730976  0.55768687]
 [0.5735974  0.68965054 0.5702088 ]
 [0.5662837  0.6933662  0.5536359 ]
 ...
 [0.47471496 0.71833104 0.43336612]
 [0.49893475 0.70974916 0.45622772]
 [0.53450066 0.7057426  0.46121603]]
```

If I try to determine the likelihood of a 0 or 2 from the prediction output, the model actually performs pretty well, particularly if I use a margin of safety (e.g., require the 2 class probability to exceed the 0 class probability by some buffer).  However, when I switch the activation of the last layer from `sigmoid` to `softmax`, the model basically doesn't work in terms of correlating classes with actual values (i.e., high probabilities of class 2 should relate to higher actual values).

I'm just trying to figure out why this might be happening, why the model predicts > 100% across all classes, and why `softmax` does not work nearly as well.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question:

Sigmoid gives a valid probability distribution only in the binary classification case. If $z$ is the pre-activation of the output layer and $N$ the number of output neurons, then 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma(z_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{1+e^{-z_i}}$$
which has no machanism that forces it to sum to $1$, since $\sigma(z_i)$ doesn't depend on $\sigma(z_j)$ for $i \neq j$.

Softmax takes care of this:
$$ \operatorname{softmax}(z_i) = \frac{e^{z_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{z_j}} $$
i.e. it takes the pre-activations of all other neurons into consideration, and in fact sums to one.

Comment: The model is coming up with similar loss values regardless of whether softmax or sigmoid is used. This leads me to believe that the labels are being converted to a one-hot encoding so that sigmoid/binary classification can be used with each output node. However, if that is true, it still doesn’t answer the question as to why the percentages are so high, and again the sigmoid model appears to be useful while the softmax version is not.

Comment: And just to clarify, I realize that the sigmoid model would generally produce combined outputs not equal to 1 in total, but it’s the fact that the predictions are consistently well above 1 that’s confusing.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong, without the data and being able to reproduce the output. Note that in your question, there is a typo in (loss=""sparse_categorical_crossentropy). The code probably wouldn't compile if it also had this typo, but just to check. Also what optimizer are you using?

Comment: I fixed the typo (initially had a variable there) and added the optimizer (Adam).  The x data is prior EURUSD price data expressed as +/- percentage changes from each prior period and y data is the +/- change at some future period, but then encoded as 0, 1, or 2 depending on whether the future change exceeds a positive or negative threshold.  The data is very noisy so it’s understandable that the model could fail easily, but I’ve validated and re-validated it many times.